# Can I connect Mini-PCI WiFi card to Mini-PCI slot for UWB?

Tags: laptop, minipci

I recently discovered, that wifi card ((Dell Wireless WLAN 1397/1510 Half Mini Card) from my new laptop (Dell XPS 1647) is terribly slow and is limiting my internet connection speed. I fought that I could replace this card with one from my old laptop (Intel® Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN). unfortunately there is only enough space for halfcard. However there is free full sized mini-PCI slot for UWB card. Will it work if I plug this wifi card into that slot (assuming that I will be able to connect antenna cables)?
Best regards,

Michał

Comment: It should work - and I believe that model has two full sized slots, though you may have one being taken up by a Bluetooth module.  You could always just pop the card in and see if the OS detects it - if it does, then you can come up with next steps to figuring out how to get the antenna connected to it.

Comment: What information and detail led you to believe it is the wifi card causing the internet connection speed to be slow? It could be a problem within the network, bandwidth issue, ISP problems, DOS attacks on your network, etc. Let us know how you came about that assumption.

And yes plugging in the old wifi card into the UWB slots will work fine.